# Create a Cron to refresh Lifetime or Daily Statistics in Magento

Tags: php, magento, cron

I wanna know how to create a cron to refresh the lifetime or daily stadistics in magento, I've read tons of pages about how to do that, but can't manage to work.
Following this question:

[Is it possible to refresh the Lifetime or Daily Statistics in magento with a cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044936/is-it-possible-to-refresh-the-lifetime-or-daily-statistics-in-magento-with-a-cro)

My question is what should be put in the refresh_stadistics.php, or in any .php that is going to execute by the cron.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is a great example how to do that. http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/

You should create a record for a cron task in your module's config.xml and then create a PHP function which will trigger statistic calculation.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I'm kind of a newbie in terms of php, what should I write in the php file that will be triggered?